# Regarding date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

Here's my query:

```
select * 
 from test n
WHERE lower(process_name) like 'test%'
  AND (   test_id is NULL 
       OR TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-6),'YYYYMM') > TO_CHAR(n.process_date,'YYYYMM')
```

I want check whether date field `process_date` is greater than 6 months in the query.

Comment: This id Oracle SQL. "mysql" and "plsql" tags should be removed

Comment: PL/SQL is "procedural extension language for SQL" (see wikipedia), where you have IF, FOR, Cursors, and in which you implement stored procedures etc. In OP we have just plain SQL. So, remove "plsql" tag. (Yes, I'm nagging :)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov: PLSQL is an extension of SQL - that includes string, date, and/or numeric functionality.  IE: ADD_MONTHS is not supported on any other database, just like how [DATEADD is TSQL specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: To be completely pedantic, In Oracle, PL/SQL and SQL are seperate languages. They are documented in seperate manuals, implemented by seperate engines, etc. "SQL and PL/SQL are fundamental to all Oracle application development. SQL is the language used to query and modify Oracle databases. PL/SQL is used to create and call triggers, stored procedures and functions, and PL/SQL packages." http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=5&frame=#sql_and_pl_sql_languages

Comment: _continuing pedantic spiel_ That said, the common use of the `PLSQL` tag on StackOverFlow covers both the PL/SQL language and SQL on the Oracle platform. Trying to get things properly tagged is tilting at windmills.

Comment: @Arav: Is the query you have giving you the results you want and you want to see if a better way exists? Or are the results wrong? If wrong, what tests have you done with actual results and expected results that show the error.

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Proper tagging is entirely semantic/arbitrary, especially at five tags.

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Unless you can turn off PLSQL support in Oracle, while the documentation makes the distinction I don't see how it holds up.  PLSQL supports SQL--SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE--and then adds to it, so calling it an "extension" is a valid description.  MySQL has yet to give a name for their functionality, but there's certainly functionality unique to MySQL--does this mean it's still just "SQL"?  I don't think this is pedantic so much as philosophical...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: PL/SQL does offer tight integeration with SQL, including the parsing and passing to the SQL engine of DML, but not DDL. `begin create table t (c number); end;` PL/SQL statements must be terminated with a `;`. Not so with SQL. `begin execute immediate 'create table t (c number);'; end;`

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Granted, but I still see the use of statement delimiters as a valid extension of SQL.  TSQL uses `GO` for moderate equivalence to PLSQL's `;` (or SQLPlus's `/` for that matter).  They wouldn't exist if there wasn't a need, and the fact the functionality exists in more than one extension is telling (IMO). ANSI is desperate to consolidate all this dissimilar syntax that should've been addressed in SQL - while TSQL and PLSQL may be currently distinct from SQL, it's very likely this won't always be the case.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: not TSQL does not use `GO`, the client side tools use `GO` to figure out where to break stuff into chunks to send to the server, where the TSQL interpreter sits. (Excactly like SQL*PLus's `/`. And also exactly like SQL*PLus when it sees a `;` at the end of the line of SQL, those semicolons are not sent to the server. Sorry I didn't point out that both chunks of code in prior comment produce errors because they are mixing PL/SQL and SQL in ways that don't work.

Comment: OMG Ponies: And this is becomming too much for comments to something about date handling. Go ahead and have the last word. I'm done discussing here.

Comment: @Shannon Severance: Sorry if I came off as adversarial, it wasn't my intention.  You're right - SO isn't meant for discussion, but I did find this interesting.  I've always enjoyed reading and respect your answers and comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an Oracle instance handy to test if Oracle will do implicit data type conversion on the TO_CHAR results being that it will be entirely numeric.  Still, seems over complicated to me when comparing to a TRUNC'd DATE value...

### For records that are six months or older in Oracle:

```
n.process_date <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -6)
```

If you want older but not including six months exactly - remove the equals operator:

```
n.process_date < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -6)
```

### For records that are six months or older in MySQL:

```
n.process_date <= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

If you want older but not including six months exactly - remove the equals operator:

```
n.process_date < DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

For MySQL, [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) is performing similar to Oracle's TRUNC.

Comment: Is the tochar query listed in post is a correct way of doing?
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),-6),'YYYYMM') > TO_CHAR(n.process_date,'YYYYMM')

Comment: @Arav: I don't think TO_CHAR is necessary - you already have the DATE to compare with

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I guess his intension is to compare month numbers, see 2nd SELECT in my post

Comment: I want to compare only YYYYMM part of date.  How can i modify the above query

Comment: @Arav: `LAST_DAY(process_date) < ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), -6)` this is guaranteed by Oracle to give same result as YYYYMM

Comment: Although this disables the index again - unless we create a functional index on LAST_DAY(process_date). However, I think process_date <  ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE)),-6) + 1 should give the right result - for today, 12th August, it gives a cut-off of midnight on 1st March 2010.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM test
 WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN( SYSDATE, process_date ) > 6
```

MONTHS_BETWEEN( date1, date2) returns (date1 - date2), so order of args is significant

If you want the **months' numbers** to differ by 6, for example if this is wrong  for you

```
    MONTHS_BETWEEN( 'JUN 13 2010', 'JAN 16 2010') == 5.9
```

Then you should:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM test
 WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN( LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), LAST_DAY(process_date) ) >= 6
```

Last days of months are guaranteed to compare correctly and return whole number

---

**NOTE**: both those queries will not use index on "process_date", if its available. For 'indexed' solution see [post by OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472937/regarding-date-in-sql/3473056#3473056) and comments to this one

Comment: That won't be able to use an index if one exists on `process_date`.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: you are right * sigh *, I've checked this with Oracle 11gR2. Note, if behavior of the second SELECT is needed, your query also will not use index

Comment: I think(!) if a function based index on (last_day(process_date)) is created, the second query should actually benefit from that index.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, `MONTHS_BETWEEN` prevents index usage, I've checked exec plan. And anyway I realized, that `LAST_DAY` on process_date isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use DATEDIFF(). See below example.

```
DECLARE @a AS DATETIME = '2010-6-1 00:00'; -- Assignment and declaration in SQLS2008
DECLARE @b AS DATETIME = '2010-8-16 00:15';

-- usage: DATEDIFF(Interval, StartDate, EndDate)

SELECT      DATEDIFF(MONTH, @a, @b) AS MonthDifference,
            DATEDIFF(HOUR, @a, @b) AS HourDifference,
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @a, @b) AS MinuteDifference;
```

You can deduct an answer from this. Please let me know if I've missed the target.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL & Oracle, but the syntax is entirely PLSQL/Oracle.  MySQL supports [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), but it only returns the number of days between the two dates.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the notification.